# Efficient way to fill in inconsistencies in time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working on a large time series data and it is pockmarked with inconsistencies, such as a missing days, or even missing data for an hour or period. It's a 5-year record of vehicular congestion, starting from `2012-10-02 09:00:00` to `2017-05-17 23:00:00`, where the format is in `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`.

In between these timestamps (totaling 33750 rows), there are several rows that are missing. For example, there are missing data for some days of July 2014, missing data for 2 August, 02:00 till 23:00 and so on. From 2014-08-08 02:00 onwards till 2015-06-10 01:00, the whole data is missing. I would like these inconsistencies to be filled in taking into account all the features in the data frame. There are 15 columns for 33750 rows.

```py
print(main_data.columns)
Index(['date_time', 'is_holiday', 'air_pollution_index', 'humidity',
       'wind_speed', 'wind_direction', 'visibility_in_miles', 'dew_point',
       'temperature', 'rain_p_h', 'snow_p_h', 'clouds_all', 'weather_type',
       'weather_description', 'traffic_volume'],
       dtype='object')

date_time            air_pollution_index    humidity ... weather_type
2014-07-01 20:00:00  51                     25           clear             
2014-07-01 21:00:00  25                     54           clear
2014-07-01 22:00:00  20                     41           cloudy
2014-07-01 23:00:00  20                     52           fog
2014-07-04 00:00:00  18                     15           rain
2014-07-04 01:00:00  18                     56           clear
2014-07-04 06:00:00  21                     20           rain
.                                           
.
.
2014-08-08 02:00:00  10                     25           cloudy
2015-06-10 01:00:00  15                     65           clear
2015-06-10 02:00:00  54                     54           clear
2015-06-10 03:00:00  24                     84           clear
```

Those are just a handful of inconsistencies in timestamps above (cannot present every column too). I would like to specifically address missing data between 2014-08-08 to 2015-06-10 for hourly records. I know of `resample` but I believe it would disturb the whole structure of the df, also manually engineering the missing timestamps and then engineering each feature, but that would be very time consuming and expensive. Does pandas contain utilities where I could fill in the missing rows without disturbing the existing ones?

Comment: you can order the `df` by `date_time` then forward fill `ffill()` missing dates. For missing data, what I usually do is fill it with in average, if your data is quite granular, for example yours is at an hourly interval, you can take the average for the day, or for the first/last n hours of the day.

Comment: It does looks like this will require manual engineering of data. Its a challenging task and one liners won't solve it.

Comment: you could possible chain multiple functions but it would probably be a little painful, maybe one of the more experienced users can give it a shot : )

Comment: Thanks. Think I might have to manually engineer the missing data. it would take time but would be worth :)